# HDFS directory on a MAPR cluster

Tags: hdfs, mapr

I need to save my Spark Streaming checkpoint files on a HDFS directory. I can access a remote cluster which has MAPR installed on it.

But, I am not sure on which path MAPR denoting to a HDFS directory

is it `opt/mapr/..`?

Answer (score 1):

When you are connected to your MapR cluster you can run the following command:

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

This will list, like inside any HDFS cluster the list of files/folders, so you see here anything special.

So if your Spark job is running on MapR cluster you just have to point to the folder your want, for example:

```
yourRdd.saveAsTextFile("/apps/output");
```

You can do exactly the same from your development environment, but you have to install and configure the [MapR-Client](http://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/AdvancedInstallation/SettingUptheClient-mapr-client.html)

Note that you can also access MapR File System (FS) using NFS, that should run on your cluster, by default the mount point is /mapr

So you can see the content of your FS using:

```
cd /mapr/you-cluster-name/apps/output
```

`/mapr/opt` is the folder that contains the MapR installed product.

So if you look at it from a pure Spark point of view: nothing change just save/read data from a folder, if you are running in MapR this will be done in MapR-FS.